# Making lastname & email optional, when creating a customer through the admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, adminhtml

I'm working on my very first Magento project, in Magento 1.9.2.2. However I have a problem, because my client would like to be able to create customers in the Magento administration panel, without being forced to type in lastname and email, whenever he himself creates a new customer. How can I achieve this?

I found this link: http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/how-to-make-last-name-optional-in-magento-1-9/

But I'm not sure that this will also apply for my problem, since my problem is related specifically to the administration panel.

Would be very grateful, if someone could provide me with a comprehensive guide as to how I would achieve customer creation without lastname & email being required.